# How to solve => NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-workbench

I started a django project I made some models and migrations with sqlite3 but now want to use mysql and workbench to work with and after all installations when runing `python manage.py migrate` or `python manage.py runserver` I have that error, please help...
I have properly installed mysql, mysqlclient and workbench and also this is the code on my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'storedb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '2E71Blue.8',
        'PORT': 3306,
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    }
}
```

this is the traceback of the error

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-310-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-310-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-310-darwin.so

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 57, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 143, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 371, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 243, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 193, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/cecibenitez/.local/share/virtualenvs/storebackend-1ILPqCOa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

I tried installing the c package for mysqlclient, I also added the path to the .zprofile, I installed a newer version of mysql, but none of this worked
`python version 3.10.5`
`mysql  Ver 8.0.33 for macos11.7 on x86_64 (Homebrew)`
and this is my pipfile

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django = "*"
django-debug-toolbar = "*"
mysqlclient = "*"
pymysql = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.10"
```

Answer (score 2):

this fixed for me
`pip uninstall mysqlclient`
`pip install mysqlclient --no-cache-dir`

Answer (score 0):

Are you correctly installing the mysqlclient library? It relies on native modules.
`_mysql` is C code.

See documentation on how to install on your OS https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient#install

Comment: I have it installed, it shows in the pipfile and also when I run ```pip freeze```

Comment: I reinstalled and got same error